# How to create new partition in Google cloud VM instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In physical machine, I can do partition with command 'fdisk' by steps as below link:
http://puremonkey2010.blogspot.com/2017/01/linux-linux-hard-disk-format-command.html

But in Google cloud VM instance, it is not allowed to do so:

> Command (m for help): w The partition table has been altered!
>
> Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
>
> WARNING: Re-reading the partition table failed with error 16: Device
>   or resource busy. The kernel still uses the old table. The new table
>   will be used at the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or
>   kpartx(8) Syncing disks.

So supposed I have a partition as below:

```
[root@johnwiki Tasks]# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0  40G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0  20G  0 part /
```

How do I create a new partition sdb2 to use the rest 20G from sda?

Many thanks!

**Ps** I tried to look into document from google from [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk) and no proper example to show me how to.

**============= Solved =============**
It turned out that the fdisk can work as well. I just need to reboot the instance in order to reflect the action in doing partition. Otherwise I won't be able do mkfs on the /dev/sda2 (new partition).

**Reference:**
 - https://blog.gtwang.org/linux/linux-add-format-mount-harddisk/

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you want to partition the disk? You could just resize the disk to the size that you want and mount another disk to the instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some documentation in the following link that you can follow to resize the file system and partitions on a persistent disk on a Cloud VM instance.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_partitions

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback! I did complete the partition by fdisk. I just reboot the instance and the new partition can be shown by 'fdisk -l /dev/sda' Then everything went well as expectation.

Comment: Great to hear that it worked! If you're happy with my answer, if you could mark it as correct that would be great.

Comment: Done! Thanks again for your quick response.